# I am getting valueError when trying to convert word2number module in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

i have written below's code but it's giving me this `error"ValueError: Type of input is not string!` Please enter a valid number word (eg. 'two million twenty three thousand and forty nine')"

```
df.experience = df.experience.apply(w2n.word_to_num)
```

Comment: My dataset has data like "zero,one, two" I want those like '1,2,3'

Comment: The problem is probably in your dataset. How is it represented exactly? please edit your post. The following code works fine for me: `df = pd.DataFrame({"experience":['five', 'two', 'seven']})
df.experience = df.experience.apply(w2n.word_to_num)`

so the problem is not in your apply line

Comment: Yes. this problem was in my dataset and i solved it . thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

First fill the missing values(null(Na) or Nan)) using `fillna` and then `apply` your code

```
df.experience = df.experience.apply(w2n.word_to_num)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df['experience'] = df['experience'].fillna('zero')
df.experience = df.experience.apply(w2n.word_to_num)
df
```

First, fill out (Nan or Na) to 'zero' not 0.
Then try running this code.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure the column is of type **string** otherwise convert it into string by using

```
df["column_name"] = df.column_name.astype(str)
```

then try to apply

```
df["column_name"] = df.column_name.apply(word_to_num)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.experience=df.experience.fillna('zero').astype(str)
df.experience=df.experience.apply(w2n.word_to_num)
```

Comment: How is this answer different from others? I seems to use a different syntax but the process it the same, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You might be wondering why its not being executed. so for that first of all you need to do:

**Step** 1: pip install word2number in your notebook

**Step** 2: You need to import w2n by using from word2number import w2n

**Step** 3: dataframe.columnname = dataframe.columnname.fillna("zero")  to fill the zero inplace of null value.

**Step** 4: dataframe.columnname = dataframe.apply(w2n.word_to_num)

Finally with these steps you can change the word to number example five to 5.

Answer (score -1):

```
df.experience=df.experience.fillna("zero").astype(str)

df["experience"]=[w2n.word_to_num(x) for x in df.experience]
```